# ODS query from Excel returns spurious column names

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, oledb, linked-server

When retriving Excel sheet Named region it returns spurious column names

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "No value given for one or more required parameters.".
Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot execute the query "SELECT `Tbl1005`.`CUSTOMER` AS `Col1031`,`Tbl1005`.`NAME` AS `Col1032`,`Tbl1005`.` 1AA00` AS `Col1033`,`Tbl1005`.` 1AB00` AS `Col1034`,`Tbl1005`.` 1AC00` AS `Col1035`,`Tbl1005`.` 1AD00` AS `Col1036`,`Tbl1005`.` 1AE00` AS `Col1037`,`Tbl1005`.` 1AF00` AS `Col1038`,`Tbl1005`.` 1AG00` AS `Col1039`,`Tbl1005`.` 1AH00` AS `Col1040`,`Tbl1005`.` 1AL00` AS `Col1041`,`Tbl1005`.` 1AM00` AS `Col1042`,`Tbl1005`.` 1AN00` AS `Col1043`,`Tbl1005`.` 1AO00` AS `Col1044`,`Tbl1005`.` 1AP00` AS `Col1045`,`Tbl1005`.` 1AQ00` AS `Col1046`,`Tbl1005`.` 1ZA00` AS `Col1047`,`Tbl1005`.` 1ZD00` AS `Col1048`,`Tbl1005`.` 4AN00` AS `Col1049`,`Tbl1005`.` 4AO00` AS `Col1050`,`Tbl1005`.` 4ZB00` AS `Col1051`,`Tbl1005`.` 5ZA00` AS `Col1029` FROM `CPGROUPS` `Tbl1005`" against OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

How do I reslove this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard coding column names is not an option for me as I would neither know number of columns nor their names before hand.
I resoloved the issue by specifying

select * from OpenDataSource('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Data Source="\xxxx\x.xls";Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"')...cpGroups

and Allow Inproc = True, Level Zero only=1 on the Provider (ACE.Oledbb.12.0)in the SQL Server

Hope what i learnt can help somebody

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this with a sheet that had leading spaces on the first row, used as the field name.  The spreadsheet was setup as a linked server

The error message was:

Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot execute the query "SELECT `Tbl1002`.`Participant` AS `Col1019`
FROM `DATASET$` `Tbl1002`" against OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "XXXXX".

After the leading space was removed it worked.

The linked server was setup using:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'XXXXX', 
@srvproduct=N'Excel', @provider=N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
@datasrc=N'\\somewhere\some_dir\mysheet.xlsx',
@provstr=N'EXCEL 12.0;Hdr=Yes' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I received this same error for a query to dBase.  The error is caused by hitting the 255-column limit for the query result from OPENDATASOURCE.  I believe the message is just from an internal call for SQL Server loading the results into memory and parsing them into a result set.  They don't represent real column names or anything related to the final output.

I resolved the issue in my case by specifying a hard-coded column list with less than 255 total field names.

Answer (score 0):

The error went away for me when I removed leading spaces in field names as mentioned by @Jim, i.e. column headings in the spreadsheet , but also:

- **Duplicated** field names - I think this was the biggest problem
- Trailing field names